# JPA Native Queries versus 'pure' JPA persistence

Tags: java, database, performance, orm, jpa

I have a scenario where in I need to keep a log of all incoming files (flat, xml) to an application. This log table is hardly used, except for fault investigation or regulatory purposes and things like that, and data will be purged regularly.

We are using JPA 2.0 for persistence. We tried the initial prototype with pure JPA persistence using `entityManager.persist();` and `flush` immediately. But the performance was not up to the expectation. So I suggested `NativeNamedQueries` for this operation and the performance improvement was huge (300 milliseconds vs 47 milliseconds) on tests.

But the lead engineer is bit adamant on using NativeNamedQueries, saying that its coupled to the database and less maintainable and things like that.

Questions :

1. What is your take on this, in case if you had to take a decision. How often does database or schema changes happen once the application goes to production ?
2. Is there any other way to improve performance? Performance is very very critical for this application.

Its only 4 years since I started programming, but never seen a DB schema change or DB provider change happening for an existing application.

Note : We are using EclipseLink 2.3 and Oracle. Also its a fresh application that we are developing. Just in case these points makes question more clear

Comment: Ask your lead engineer to name two RDBMS that have different syntax on INSERT statements. I've spent the last 8 yrs writing DataNucleus and it supports all common RDBMS and needs no different syntax for handling all (other than upper/lower casing of identifiers depending on how the schema defined them).

Comment: @DataNucleus OMG. I cannot believe someone from DataNucleus commenting on my question. You know, you got to live with someone and their preferences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How often does database or schema changes happen once the application goes to production ?

This is immaterial to your problem at hand. The quantity of changes to database schemas does not matter. What matters is the maintainability of your database model, how well it has been designed. Most business apps will see a lot of changes being done if sufficient performance testing hasn't been done, which is sadly true for most apps.

If you are a writing a typical line-of-business application, I would expect some form of round-trip engineering between the object model and the database model to occur in development. Your DBAs ought to own and know the database model quite well, so that they can aid or perform the fine-tuning the queries issued by your ORM framework. This is keeping in mind that you may not rely on the queries issued by the ORM framework alone. All changes should preferably be done and tested in the development and integration-testing (and possibly UAT, if you have one) environments before it is rolled out to production, and as common sense would suggest, all changes would be under version control.

On the topic of coupling the queries to a database, then that is a decision your business has to take. If you are in the business of supporting multiple databases, then you ought to testing against all. Also, you should be capable of providing different distributions for supporting different databases; this is made easier if you place your native queries in database specific `orm.xml` files like `orm-oracle.xml`, `orm-mysql.xml` etc. and rename the files to `orm.xml` before you prepare a distribution. Using Maven or Ant would make the proposed change easy to implement.

> Is there any other way to improve performance? Performance is very very critical for this application.

That would depend on how well you have designed your object and data models, how well you've understood your ORM framework and how willing you are in "corrupting" your object model.

The first bit of performance tuning any application is to always measure twice and cut once. You cannot simply iterate through a list of possible solutions and try each one of them without knowing how they work and in what circumstances they are useful; okay, you could do that if your business is willing to invest time in that, but it is often not the case.

To begin, you'll need to understand why native queries are providing or appear<sup>*</sup> to provide a better performance. Maybe this has got a lot to do with the fact that you are merely inserting data, and it would be better for an ORM framework to simply issue the `INSERT` statement rather than construct one from HQL or the abstract query notation used under the hood; only a profiler will reveal the difference.

If the above is true, then you could reconsider whether your audit tables must be managed by the ORM framework. If your application is responsible for only writing to these tables and not reading from them (and it is quite possible that another app is responsible for reading the entries), then I would suspect that not managing these tables in ORM would provide better performance, especially if you use plain JDBC to issue the `INSERT` statement. The reason is quite simple - if your ORM framework is managing the entity, then it is also responsible for managing the persistence context (which now includes the class and the associated table); not having ORM manage the entity would *possibly* result in the scenario where the persistence context need not be updated at all for audit entries.

There is a healthy possibility of other performance tuning measures that you can undertake, but like I stated earlier, it would require you to understand a profiler report and estimate which possible choices would be better in your application.

<sup>*</sup> I'm afraid that unless you publish benchmarks and how you conducted them I will be skeptical of claims.

Comment: wow!! Its wonderful answer. I'll update the question with benchmarks on Monday. We don't require ORM to manage persistence context for this since its not a data of transactional nature. Also its a domain and technology stack aware middleware . That is why I went for NativeQueries for insert here. Moreover its a simple SQL insert which should work on any database.

Comment: @nobody, you don't need to. I think your comment in the other question provided another possibility for you to investigate. Since you are using a `BLOB` I think you should consult some one in your organization to see if plain files that are associated with a signature/hash would work; after all these are audit entries. The reason why it might turn out to be better is that Oracle uses a different segment for storing LOBs, instead of the segment associated with the table. I suspect that the inherent problem would be solved if you do not use a LOB in the first place.

Comment: I had thought of it. But organisation is very particular on storing in DB since it is 'secure' and we have constraints(security measures imposed) on writing to a file system in production. You know we receive 5MB file in MQ(which if my understanding is correct,  MQ is not designed for). But we have to provide best out of these constraints. so BLOB was the only option.

Comment: `which if my understanding is correct, MQ is not designed for` and the same applies to storing files of that size in a database. That's why I proposed a filesystem based solution. Besides, storing something in the DB does not automatically make an audit entry infallible; what matters is `non-repudiability` and `a validated chain of custody` and that isn't easy if you haven't segregated your audit tables from the normal business tables, and if you haven't used separate transactions for inserting audit entries.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's quite rare that you actually *DO* switch the database provider, especially once you've paid several 100k's of license for an excellent and high-performant database like Oracle. Besides, the SQL syntax variants of the `INSERT` statement are not so distinct that you wouldn't be able to switch the database, even when using native SQL, exceptionally.
2. I don't see why patching a single query that needs extra tuning is bad. Ask your lead developer why he's so strict. But before you do, use a profiler, such as JProfiler, or Yourkit to identify the exact spot that's causing the performance issues. With JPA, any of these may cause issues: caching, eager loading of dependent data (which you wouldn't need, probably), inefficient SQL generation, a bad query execution plan in your Oracle database, etc... Maybe you don't need a native query after all.
3. If performance is so critical, then maybe JPA is not good enough for the job. Have you (and your lead developer) considered other frameworks such as [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/), [MyBatis](http://mybatis.org/) or anything similar? I have understood from your comments that your main use-cases are OLAP-querying, and not OLTP, hence you might even like to use advanced Oracle features, such as analytic functions and data-warehousing functionality, for which jOOQ has native support, for instance...

Answer (score 1):

1) I have seen only 2 applications that moved from oracle to MySQL (to save on license costs) in 10 years, so it's not something that happens very often, BUT if you want to write integration tests using another database (eg hsqldb) you'll be in trouble.

About how often schema changes after an app goes to production, my answer is: A LOT!! If the app will be updated regularly, expect LOTs of changes, as usually the team understand the business better. I even worked on the project in which the schema was considerably different after one year of the app going live.

At the same time, this looks like you deferred optimizing the until the last posible time (a good thing to do) and now you need optimize the sql using some native queries (which also happens quite regularly)... What I'm trying to say is that your idea doesn't sound bad at all for me.

2) In the past I've used a mix of Hibernate and iBatis (or mybatis nowadays) for similar situations (in case you want to check iBatis). And one question, why are you doing a flush() after each persist()? You shoulnd't really need to do that.

Also, I'm quite surprised that the inserts take so much longer if they're done in EclipseLink. The calls to persist() should take almost the same amount of time as native query (I assuming they'll take longer if there is any lifecycle callbacks). I assume you've seen the sql generated by eclipseLink, is it that different?

I know my answer is not specific at all, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Why I flush soon after i receive a file is, if the file is duplicate then there's no further processing and transactions ends there. But if the file is not duplicate transaction proceeds further and could have used flush at the end. There are no lifecycle callbacks. Also the query looks almost similar. BTW its simple insert query with 6 columns one of which is a BLOB.